# Find the string matching between two data frames

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame as below.

DF1:

```
   A
Any Match
Credit
I need a debit card.
Logging
Awesome
```

I have another DataFrame as below:

DF2:

```
          B
I did not find any match.
I want a credit card.
I need a debit card.
I do not know.
I am logging into credit portal.
```

I need my output as:

```
              B                           A
     I did not find any match.        Any Match
     I want a credit card.            Credit
     I need a debit card.             I need a debit card.
     I am logging into credit portal. logging,credit
```

Here if the phrase  present in the DF1 is in any of the text present in DF2.
Print the o/p as Text and important phrase.

Comment: why it only returns `Debit` while `I need a debit card` present in both DF1 and DF2?

Comment: Please explain what you have attempted and provide a minimal example from where we can start. Also, what happens if a phrase in B contains more than one of the phrases in A, or none of them, and what if two phrases in B contain the same phrase in A. Please give more detail about the specific requirements you have for your output.

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar..Extremely sorry it was a mistake from my side. I have edited that one.

Comment: @jdehesa..I f it contains more than one phrase it should return both. if two phrases in B contain the same phrase in A, both should return same phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Fuzzywuzzy`:

```
import pandas as pd
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

matched_entities = []

for row in df1.index:
    name1 = vendor_df.get_value(row,"A")
    for columns in df2.index:
        name2=df2.get_value(columns,"B")
        matched_token=fuzz.partial_ratio(name1,name2)
        if matched_token> 80:
            matched_vendors.append([A,B])

df_partial_ratio = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'], data=matched_entities)
```

In your DB if `fuzz.partial_ratio` doesn't work try  `fuzz.ratio` or `fuzz.token_sort_ratio`. These two can be implemented by changing one line of above code by below codes:

```
matched_token=fuzz.ratio(name1,name2)
```

OR

```
matched_token=fuzz.token_sort_ratio(name1,name2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. First, define a lookup function that matches "normalized" text, e.g. lowercased:

```
def lookup(x, values):
    for value in values:
        if value.lower() in x.lower():
            return value
```

Then apply this function to your DF2:

```
dfB['A'] = dfB['B'].apply(lambda x: lookup(x, dfA['A']))
```

Which should give you:

```
    B                           A
0   I did not find any match.   Any Match
1   I want a credit card.       Credit
2   I need a debit card.        Debit
3   I do not know.              None
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df1['B'] = float('nan')

pos = 0
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1['A'][i].lower() in df2['B'][j].lower():
            df1['B'].iloc[pos] = df2['B'][j]
            pos+=1
            break

df1.dropna(axis=0)
```

output

```
                     A                          B
0            Any Match  I did not find any match.
1               Credit      I want a credit card.
2  I need a debit card       I need a debit card.
```